# Why use "ojalá" rather than "desearía" when saying "I wish my Spanish were better"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

In this link I find several phrases that can be used for "I wish", and using the example given I would have expected the translation of "I wish my Spanish were better" would be "Desearía que mi Espanol fuera mejor".  http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/ask

However, in looking up precisely that phrase on a forum, most people suggested "Ojalá mi español fuera mejor".  Can anyone explain why you'd prefer "ojalá" over "desearía"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find "ojalá" (a word of Arab origin) to be superior to "desearía" or even to "me gustaría/querría" (I'd like), but only a little more colloquial. You also have the less usual "Si tan solo..." (which we we usually punctuate with an elision or exclamation mark to emphasize the unlikelihood of your wish coming true).

All of these options are fine:

- Ojalá mi español fuera mejor.
- Desearía que mi español fuera mejor.
- Me gustaría que mi español fuera mejor.
- Querría que mi español fuera mejor.
- Si tan solo mi español fuera mejor... / ¡Si tan solo mi español fuera mejor!

Comment: Also, depending on the context, *Desearía que…* may suggest that your Spanish getting better depends on someone or something else making it possible; while *Ojalá…* just expresses the wish.